# Microsoft Graph List Group Members OData Query Parameters Bug

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API to list the members in a group. My API request looks like this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[group id]/members`

This works and returns the group members. However, when I try to filter the fields returned for each user using the `$select` query param, it is returning incorrect data. The request I am making is

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[group id]/members?$select=id`

It is returning a `200` response, but the json data returned is not being filtered. Rather, **it is returning more data than was returned by the original call without the OData Query Parameter**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue! Microsoft Graph team is working on a fix. We will respond on this post with an update in a few days.

Comment: Hi @mattnedrich again, thank you for reporting this issue. We have identified the code bug and are actively working on releasing the fix. It is expected to roll out to all customers no later than in the next two weeks.